# EBS Snapshot; Restarting EC2 Instance before Snapshot complete

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

It is my understanding that when you create an EBS Snapshot, any data written to the volume up to the time that the snapshot was started, will be included. I.e, even if the snapshot is in the "pending" state, it is still safe to write to the EBS volume.

Is this still considered the case for taking EBS snapshots of root volumes? In the [documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/create-snapshot.html), it is stated that when you create a snapshot for Amazon EBS volumes that serve as root devices, you should stop the instance before taking the snapshot.

Does this imply that we can stop the instance, begin the snapshot, and then restart the instance before the snapshot has completed? The reason I'm asking is because our snapshots are taking >15 minutes, which is timing out our Snapshot Management Lambda before it can restart the instance.

Answer (score 0):

It should be safe, see https://serverfault.com/questions/548731/can-i-re-attach-my-ebs-while-a-snapshot-is-pending

You should stop the instance when creating a root volume snapshot because you can not unmount root volume beforehand, hence you would risk your snapshot would be corrupted.